# Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'

Tags: python, json, odoo

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en python que obtiene algunos campos customizados del modelo **sale.order** para un servidor externo de etiquetas, el archivo ya funcionaba en una versión de **Odoo v12** pero recientemente estoy migrando este proceso para **Odoo v15**, sin embargo, al enviar el json que trae de vuelta la info en los campos manda el siguiente error:

```
2022-08-30 22:23:02,868 16792 ERROR yuju odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest: 
400 Bad Request: <function Home.index at 0x000002F31ABDD318>, /: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'
```

Esta es la configuración del programa y la función que manda a llamar la info desde odoo:

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

server_url  ='http://localhost:8090/'
db_name = 'yuju'
username = 'odoo'
password = '1234'
json_endpoint = "%s/jsonrpc" % server_url
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

def get_json_payload(service, method, *args):
    return json.dumps({
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": 'call',
    "params": {
    "service": service,
    "method": method,
    "args": args
    },
    "id": 6,
    })

user_id = 6
def get_order_id(name):
    try:
        payload = get_json_payload("common", "version")
        response = requests.post(json_endpoint, data=payload, headers=headers)

        if user_id:
            search_domain = [['name', '=', name]]
            payload = get_json_payload("object", "execute_kw",db_name, user_id, password,'sale.order', 'search_read', [search_domain, ['marketplace_order_id', 'name', 'seller_marketplace']],
            {'limit': 1})
            print(payload)
            res = requests.post(json_endpoint, data=payload, headers=headers)#.json()
            #logging.info(default_code+str(res))
            print (res)
            marketplace_order_id = res['result'][0]['marketplace_order_id']
            print('marketplace_order_id', marketplace_order_id)
            seller_marketplace = res['result'][0]['seller_marketplace']
            order_odoo_id = res['result'][0]['id']

            return dict(marketplace_order_id = marketplace_order_id, seller_marketplace =seller_marketplace, order_odoo_id = order_odoo_id )
        else:
            logging.error("Failed: wrong credentials")  
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error ('Error:'+str(e))
        return False
```

Debugeando pude ver que es justo en la línea que contiene lo siguiente donde se genera el error:

```
res = requests.post(json_endpoint, data=payload, headers=headers)#.json()
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN

El error anterior era debido a que la variable **json_endpoint** ya tiene una diagonal y chocaba con la digonal final de la variable **server_url**, coloco a continuación la correción:

```
server_url  ='http://localhost:8090' #aquí estaba el fallo
json_endpoint = "%s/jsonrpc" % server_url
```

además instalé en odoo una aplicación que viene por defecto llamada **test_rpc** para solicitudes rpc y **json-rpc** como librería de python

El error que tengo ahora es este:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 141, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 41, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 176, in execute
    res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 160, in execute_cr
    result = odoo.api.call_kw(recs, method, args, kw)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\api.py", line 457, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\api.py", line 430, in _call_kw_model
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\models.py", line 5012, in search_read
    records = self.search(domain or [], offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\models.py", line 1810, in search
    res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\models.py", line 4675, in _search
    if expression.is_false(self, args):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\osv\expression.py", line 229, in is_false
    elif token[1] == 'in' and not (isinstance(token[2], Query) or token[2]):
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perdón que me responda solo, pero esta es la solución (un tanto simple) al problema que tenía.

En lugar de generar un JSON con la función **get_json_payload**, estructuré el JSON directamente en la función de **get_order_id**,

```
    def get_order_id(name):
        try:
            payload = get_json_payload("common", "version")
            response = requests.post(json_endpoint, data=payload, headers=headers)
    
            if user_id:
                search_domain = [['name', '=', name]]
                #payload = get_json_payload("object", "execute",db_name, user_id, password,'sale.order', 'search_read', [search_domain, ['marketplace_order_id', 'name', 'seller_marketplace']],{'limit': 1})
#Aquí sustituí la variable payload que llama a la función que arma el JSON
#estructurando directamente el JSON dentro de esta misma función
                payload = json.dumps({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "call", "params": {"service": "object", "method": "execute", "args": [db_name, user_id, password, "sale.order", "search_read",
                                        search_domain, ['marketplace_order_id', 'name', 'seller_marketplace']]}})
                print(payload)
                res = requests.post(json_endpoint, data=payload, headers=headers).json()
                #logging.info(default_code+str(res))
                #print (res)
                marketplace_order_id = res['result'][0]['marketplace_order_id']
                print('marketplace_order_id', marketplace_order_id)
                seller_marketplace = res['result'][0]['seller_marketplace']
                order_odoo_id = res['result'][0]['id']
    
                return dict(marketplace_order_id = marketplace_order_id, seller_marketplace =seller_marketplace, order_odoo_id = order_odoo_id )
            else:
                logging.error("Failed: wrong credentials")
                return False
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error ('Error:'+str(e))
            return False
```